# Exportando meu projeto, erro proguard

Tags: android, proguard-android

Exportando sem o proguard tudo ocorre normalmente, mas quando ativo da esse erro:

```
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20: can't find referenced method 'android.app.RemoteInput[] getRemoteInputs()' in class android.app.Notification$Action
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20: can't find referenced method 'android.os.Bundle getExtras()' in class android.app.Notification$Action
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$Action$Builder
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$Action$Builder
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$Action$Builder
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$Action$Builder
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$Action$Builder
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String getGroup()' in class android.app.Notification
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String getSortKey()' in class android.app.Notification
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$Action$Builder
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20$Builder: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder setLocalOnly(boolean)' in class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20$Builder: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder setGroup(java.lang.String)' in class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20$Builder: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder setGroupSummary(boolean)' in class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20$Builder: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder setSortKey(java.lang.String)' in class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20$Builder: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$Action$Builder
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20$Builder: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$Action$Builder
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20$Builder: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$Action$Builder
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20$Builder: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$Action$Builder
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20$Builder: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$Action$Builder
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20$Builder: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder addAction(android.app.Notification$Action)' in class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20$Builder: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20$Builder: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20$Builder: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$Action$Builder
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput$Builder
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput$Builder
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput$Builder
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput$Builder
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput$Builder
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput$Builder
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput$Builder
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: there were 37 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] Warning: there were 9 unresolved references to program class members.
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp]  at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp]  at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp]  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2014-09-14 01:59:01 - meuapp]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20: can't find referenced method 'android.app.RemoteInput[] getRemoteInputs()' in class android.app.Notification$Action
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20: can't find referenced method 'android.os.Bundle getExtras()' in class android.app.Notification$Action
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$Action$Builder
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$Action$Builder
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$Action$Builder
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$Action$Builder
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$Action$Builder
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String getGroup()' in class android.app.Notification
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String getSortKey()' in class android.app.Notification
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$Action$Builder
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20$Builder: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder setLocalOnly(boolean)' in class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20$Builder: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder setGroup(java.lang.String)' in class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20$Builder: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder setGroupSummary(boolean)' in class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20$Builder: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder setSortKey(java.lang.String)' in class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20$Builder: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$Action$Builder
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20$Builder: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$Action$Builder
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20$Builder: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$Action$Builder
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20$Builder: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$Action$Builder
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20$Builder: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$Action$Builder
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20$Builder: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder addAction(android.app.Notification$Action)' in class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20$Builder: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20$Builder: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi20$Builder: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$Action$Builder
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput$Builder
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput$Builder
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput$Builder
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput$Builder
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput$Builder
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput$Builder
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput$Builder
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: android.support.v4.app.RemoteInputCompatApi20: can't find referenced class android.app.RemoteInput
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: there were 37 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] Warning: there were 9 unresolved references to program class members.
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp]  at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp]  at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp]  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2014-09-14 02:07:37 - meuapp]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

meu proguard:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {    
native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

Será que o erro está no proguard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolvi meu problema adicionando no proguard.cfg o seguinte código:

-dontwarn android.support.**

> com base nessa explicação:
>   https://github.com/exmo/equizmo-android/wiki/Ofuscando-aplicativos-Android

"Se seu projeto utiliza a biblioteca Android Support, para fazer uso de Fragments e outras funcionalidades da versão 4.0 do Android, o Proguard lança vários warnings ao tentar ofuscar o código. Esta entrada serve para ele ignorar esses warnings, fazendo a ofuscação concluir com sucesso. Segundo a própria documentação do Android, é seguro fazer isso."

Answer (score 0):

Eu tentaria não ofuscar as classes do AppCompat:

```
-keep class android.support.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.** { *; }
```